# Access query issue to show partial hits and use partial as the query to get a hit

Tags: ms-access

I have a Access DB 2 tables
table 1 contains audited machines with machine specs
The other with a list of disk drive models with a second column to say if its an SSD or Mech Drive.
Unfortunately the 1st Table has in the disk model olumn any USB drives found as well so and example would look like this:
SAMSUNG MZNTY256HDHP-000 SCSI Disk Device,Apricorn Padlock 3.0 USB Device,SanDisk ExtremePro USB Device

vs

SAMSUNG MZNTY256HDHP-000 SCSI Disk Device

Unfortunately when it hit records like the above it completely ignores the entry in my disk model table and provides a blank field rather than SSD.

Any ideas on how I can get it to only compare text before the 1st comma and provide a hit.

I appreciate any assistance on this.

Comment: use `like field1 & "*"` for joining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of joining the 2 tables, extract the piece you want first - put a field in your query that is something like

```
ExtractedName:left(DiskName(instr(DiskName & ",", ",")-1)
```

Then add a criteria for this field to select records that match the name in the 2nd table.

Note - appending the extra comma to DiskName handles the situation where there is not already a comma in the name - otherwise, those names would return a 0 for the Instr function, and would not match the 2nd table (and would cause an error).

Corrected syntax:

```
ExtractedName:left(Physical_Disk_Models,instr(Physical_Disk_Models & ",", ",")-1)
```

Comment: That doesn't seem right. You're invoking `DiskName` like a function

Comment: Sorry I clearly am doing something wrong here. I have opened a new query and added only the table with machine specifications. And in the Field above table I have added ExtractedName:left(Physical_Disk_Models(instr(Physical_Disk_Models & ",", ",")-1)    Unfortunately I get an error The expression you entered is missing a closing parenthesis bracket. I have also tried this format ExtractedName:left([Physical_Disk_Models](instr([Physical_Disk_Models] & ",", ",")-1). Please advise what I have done wrong thanks

Comment: You're both right, I had the wrong syntax (used ( instead of ,)  I edited my answer above.

Comment: You are a gentleman and a scholar thank you for your fast assistance on this and that worked like a charm. really appreciated :)

Comment: Glad to help & thanks for letting me know it worked - would you mind accepting the answer?

Comment: Apologies accepted and thanks again